# GSM modules or WiFi?

Tags: wireless, gsm, wearable

I'm trying to work on a prototype wearable indoor and I am really confused as to how I am going to transfer data fetched from the GPS device to the server. Is `GSM module` the best option or should I go for `WiFi`? How can this be achieved and what are my best options?

Answer (score 1):

If your final product is designed to be worn outside you have to go down the GSM path as it work in a wider range. If it is indoors only Wi-Fi is more appropriate.

The reason is cost. GSM covers a wider range, but it requires a more expensive module, and you also have recurring costs from the cellular carrier and running a publicly accessible server (since you need at least either a static IP address or a domain name, and either of them cost money.) Wi-Fi, however, covers only inside and immediate around the building the access point is set up, but requires only a cheaper module, and since it is, after all, LAN, so there is no recurring cost other than electricity bill (which you also have to pay if you go down the GSM path anyway)

Comment: Can you offer more on why? My suggestion to the OP would have been more on mobility required and who controls the WiFi before answering. I don't see how indoors/outdoors by itself determines WiFi.

Comment: @kenny Cost. GSM can have long standing recurring cost from a carrier (and a higher initial cost too) but Wi-Fi have only a lower one-time cost. Also running a server that is publicly accessible also cost more as you need at least either a fixed IP address or a domain name, and both cost money.

Comment: that's a good point. It's a lot more than just inside/outside.

Comment: @kenny Since the range of Wi-Fi is usually limited to indoors and immediate around a building you might as well categorize your use case as indoors or outdoors.

Comment: If it's indoors, the GPS isn't going to be much good in the first place.